# If $f$ is the limit of polynomials with only real zeros, then all zeros of $f$ are real

Tags: complex-analysis, roots

#### Problem

> Let $f$ be a non-constant entire function. Suppose that there is a sequence of polynomials ${P_n(z)}$,  $n=1,2,...$ such that

1. $P_n(z)$ converges uniformly to $f$ on every bounded set in
   $\mathbb{C}$
2. All zeros of $P_n$ are real.

Prove that all zeros of $f$ are real

#### Progress

I have tried [Hurwitz's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz%27s_theorem_(complex_analysis)) but I could not figure out how to go after that. By Hurwitz, I know that the sequence and $f $ have the same number of zeros in $B(a;R)$. But that's about it. Also, I think the sequence of zeros of $P_n$ converge to the zeros of $f$, with respect to their magnitude and multiplicity. But I really do not know how to show it.

Comment: Please read the advice on [asking good questions](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/9959). Also, do you know the  Hurwitz theorem?

Comment: Thank you. I have tried Hurwitz's Theorem but I could not figure out how to go after that. By Hurwitz, I know that the sequence and f have the same number of zeros in B(a;R) . But that's about it. Also, I think the sequence of zeros of P_n converge to the zeros of f, with respect to their magnitude and multiplicity . But I really do not know how to show it.

Comment: The statement on wikipedia also says that the zeroes converge to the zero of $f$.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose $u$ is a non real zero of $f$. There exists $R>0$ such that the closed disk with center $u$ and radius $R$ do not intersect the real line, and such that $f(z)\not =0$ on the circle $C$ centered at $u$ and of radius $R$. Then there exists $m>0$ such that $|f(z)|\geq m$ on $C$. Now there exists  a large integer $N$ such that $\displaystyle |f(z)-P_N(z)|<\frac{m}{2}<m\leq |f(z)|$ on the circle $C$. By Rouché's theorem, $f$ and $P_N$ have the same number of zeroes in the disk $D(u,R)$. As $f$ have at least $u$ as zero, $P_N$ has a zero in $D(u,R)$, hence non real, contradiction.

Comment: +1.  You do not have to suppose that $u$ is a zero for this argument to work.  That makes it a direct proof.